# Will I be able to exit airport during return trip with Schengen single entry visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, transit

I will be traveling through Schengen on a single(probably) entry Schengen visa.

My return trip leaves from Rome and has a long layover in Amsterdam, will I be able to exit the airport and see Amsterdam during this time? Or is my flight from Rome considered the exit from the Schengen zone even though it passes through another Schengen country? 
Is the visa marked as used when I leave Rome?
Thanx

Comment: Yes, you will exit the Schengen zone at the Amsterdam airport, so you can leave the airport. Just remember about checked in baggage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rome-Amsterdam is effectively a domestic flight, so you don't clear passport control until Amsterdam.

So yes, you can exit the airport - you just pass the baggage hall and Exit.